# Logback in embedded Jetty 9

Tags: java, logging, logback, embedded-jetty

I would like to log my embedded jetty app with logback and define the log level into a logback.xml config file.

Actually, I had a Spark Java server and all was right, but since I migrated to an embedded Jetty directly, my configuration is not taken into account anymore.

Comment: Why _should_ your configuration be taken into account?

Comment: Because it was taking it into account with Spark Java server. And Spark Java server is using embedded Jetty.

Answer (score 0):

Spark Java has slf4j-simple as dependence, try to add an exclusion on maven dependencies definition.
In my case i use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and works right.